# Derivative of norm in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I read (p. 485 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that the Fréchet derivative of norm (non-linear) functional $p:H\to\mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto\|x\|$ is $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ for all $x\ne 0$, which I think to be intended as the linear functional, which is what the Fréchet derivative $p'(x)\in \mathscr{L}(H,\mathbb{R})$ should be, defined by $h\mapsto\langle\frac{x}{\|x\|},h\rangle$. I suspect $H$ is intended to be a *real* Hilbert space, although Kolmogorov-Fomin's says nothing about the scalar field.

As always, before asking here, I searched the Internet, but only find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103207/finding-the-derivative-of-the-norm) page from this very site. Can anybody point to a proof of $p'(x)h=\langle\frac{x}{\|x\|},h\rangle$? I $\infty$-ly thank you!

Comment: Yes, $\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}$ is to be interpreted as the map $h\mapsto \langle h, \lVert x\rVert^{-1}\cdot x\rangle$, and if $H$ is a complex Hilbert space rather than a real, we need to take the real part - which means the map is real-differentiable, but not complex-differentiable. There is not much to add to the argument in the linked thread, perhaps splitting $x\mapsto \lVert x\rVert$ into $(\sqrt{\,\cdot\,})\circ (x \mapsto \lVert x\rVert^2)$ makes it easier, since $\lVert x+h\rVert^2 = \lVert x\rVert^2 + 2\langle x,h\rangle + \lVert h\rVert^2$ makes the derivative better to see.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you so much!!!